# Apache Drill with mongoDB : Getting issue while joining two collection

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

As i am new in apache drill and mongodb need someone's help

I have to fetch data after joining two tables
Table1  courierrecords
Table2  customers

query:-

```sql
select courierrecords.shipmentReferenceNumber1, customers.name 
from courierrecords
join customers on courierrecords.customer_id=customers.customerId;
```

getting below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zERkm.png)

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCbC6.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHLyh.png)

Any help here. also any ideas how to join with ObjectId's

I have tried many examples which I find on internet as well as in Apache documentation but still getting errors

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: To add to the comment above: the goal is for future users to be able to find your question when they face the same problem.  That's only possible if you put your command and error message in text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to MongoDB ObjectIDs from Drill SQL using the column name `_id`, e.g.

```sql
select courierrecords.shipmentReferenceNumber1, customers.name 
from courierrecords join customers on courierrecords._id = customers._id;
```

Please also see [DRILL-8190](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-8190?) which describes a recently fixed bug relating to MongoDB collection joins. Drill 1.20.3 was released a few hours ago and includes a fix for Drill-8190, so please test again using Drill 1.20.3.